# python 2.7 virtual env - No module named lxml.objectify

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv, lxml

I'm using virtualenv with Python 2.7 for a Django project, on Google App Engine sandbox on Windows environment.
I try to use this [amazon api library](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) which requires lxml as a dependency.

After installing lxml (and all other dependencies) and trying to import amazon api module, I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: No module named lxml.objectify

objectify module exists in the correct folder.
I searched online for a solution and saw that installing lxml on Windows can be pain in the ass, but couldn't find a solution.

What I already tried:

- Uninstalling and installing lxml
- Installing version 3.8.0 and 3.7.3
- Installing lxml as pip or binary installer
- Installing lxml from whl package

Did someone faced this issue and was able to solve it?

Cheers!

Comment: Try to find `whl` package. This is strange because bin installer should help

Comment: @marni I downloaded whl package also. btw the installer only let you install lxml in python default folder (c:\python27) and not in the virtualenv folder. So I installed it and copied the files. No success ther.

Comment: Are you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287842/4900574

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately still without success

Comment: And from this also: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Comment: If this is a standard environment GAE app try ditching venv and follow the official documentation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885155/python-virtualenv-no-module-error/45885386#45885386

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python virtualenv No module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885155/python-virtualenv-no-module-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lxml` is one of App Engine's [built-in third party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27).

To use it, you need to:

add it to the libraries directive of your [app.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library):

```
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: 3.7.3
```

and [Install it locally using pip](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#local_development), because it's not included in the SDK:

```
pip install lxml==3.7.3
```

or install via the [vendoring process](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library).

```
pip install --target lib lxml==3.7.3
```

If `lxml` is not added to `app.yaml` you will see the dev server will report an `ImportError`, regardless of how `lxml` was installed.

Comment: Man, I can't believe I missed it. Thanks so much!